# time sync with ntpd

Tags: linux

I run Debian on several systems, and their times do not seem to stay in sync. I can run *ntpdate* manually, but I thought that I should have an *ntpd* running that would automate that.

I did check with *apt* and *apt-cache* but don't find any *ntpd* (or associated *ntpq*), not any such names in my system (locate...), but *ntp-doc* does still describe them.

Looking around I see that there is an *ntpdate-debian* command, and it uses */etc/default/ntpdate* for servers (instead of the standard */etc/ntp.conf*), but  even thought that file is there and has "yes" indicated to use *ntp.conf*, it fails with "no servers can be used", although *ntpdate* works fine. Is this just a layer over *ntpdate*, any reason to use it instead?

So, why are they missing, do I need them, how do I automate time updates?

Associated, two of my machines are virtualized on a MSoft VM, how is it that their clocks drift, and both to different values? (The underlying Windows machine clock seems stable). I see a few old notes about time & ntp problems on VMware, didn't find anything either current or relating to MSoft VMs. Anything I did see says just to use ntpd, but as above, ...?!

Comment: For the Hyper-V VMs you need to enable integration services. I believe there's an apt package or something similar. I would expect `ntpd` to be part of the base OS, but maybe I'm used to more advanced *nix clones.

Comment: Thanks - good pointer. But from the MSoft site they seem to only support SUSE & Red Hat.

Comment: It's also odd that two identical (cloned) Debian VMs on the same system have very different clock drifts. One was .4 secs off after 2 days, the other 49 seconds.

Comment: If ntp is installed running, can you post the output of `ntpq -p`?

Comment: (See below) - The ntpq output is hard to format in a comment, but I think the useful part is the (delay,offset,jitter) results - (.189,2.9,.1), 3.6,2.9,.1),

Comment: ntpq output from a cloned version of the same system on the same VM; (delay,offset,jitter) = 79.8,3.3,15),(103,1.5,15),(72,8,20),(55,12,17)

Answer (score 1):

The package you are looking for is `ntp`, which provides daemon and utilities for time synchronization.

Comment: As noted above, I already installed ntp, and also ntpdate-debian, and ntp-doc. The lack of automatic synchronization ntpd-style lead to the above question.

Comment: Sorry guthrie, it wasn't clear from your question that ntp was installed. If so, maybe there's some kind of configuration glitch in /etc/ntp.conf? Can you post it? ntp has worked out of the box on all my servers.

Comment: Thanks. I think the _ntp.conf_ is ok, since _ntpdate_ works fine manually. There is no ntp.conf file but since I don't seem to have ntpd (which uses it), I don't think the file is used anyway. I wanted some automation which I think ntpd is supposed to provide. (I do have to give ntpdate the server argument, which I would have thought would come from the .conf file.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have been some install problem, I reinstalled ntp and it seems to now be corrected and ok. I don't know how it went wrong before, since *ntpdate* was there, but not the others.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stock ntp.conf from the you may want to look adding the `tinker panic 0` option to your `ntp.conf`.  This will permit it to ignore clock jumps that wouldn't normally happen on physical hardware.

If your hypervisor is trying to do time-sync then you should get rid of ntp.  Only one service should be trying to manage time within the VM.  If you have an agent for your hypervisor installed, and NTP running at the same time, then badness will result.

Since you have the ntp daemon installed, make sure it is started, and then verify that it is actually running by using the `ntpq -p` command.  This command will report which peer was selected, and some stats about NTP.

```
#ntpq -p -n
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+192.168.78.130   172.16.16.34    2 u   81  128  377    0.189    2.935   0.164
*172.23.206.10   172.16.16.34    2 u   72  128  377    3.648    2.902   0.109
+216.129.110.22  69.36.224.15     2 u   10  128  377   92.224  -23.697   0.704
```

Comment: I am not sure how to tell if I have the situation you describe with a hypervisor agent for time sync. The ntpq output is (Hard to format in a comment!): `alpha:/home/net# ntpq -p -n
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
+71.6.217.53     131.107.13.100   2 u   13  256  377   77.277   -4.492   4.622
*108.71.253.20   .GPS.            1 u    1  256  373  104.012  -14.622   7.761
+74.118.152.85   69.36.224.15     2 u  147  256  277   69.100  -10.436   5.534
-97.107.134.28   128.4.40.12      3 u  223  256  377   38.207   -7.521   5.509
`

Comment: Fighting with the comment editor!  - The ntpq output is hard to format in a comment, but I think the useful part is the (delay,offset,jitter) results - (.189,2.9,.1), 3.6,2.9,.1),

Comment: You could have just updated your question with the new information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a cron job for it?  This is the script I use on ubuntu-server 12.04:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
' > /etc/cron.daily/ntpdate
chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/ntpdate
```

This is the same approach [recommended by racksapce](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/Ubuntu_Intrepid_-_Syncing_time_with_ntpd).

Comment: bad idea, creates gaps in the time continuum

Comment: Can you share more details?